# Touch based scroll not working on devices

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I've never come across this before. I just built a single page layout website for a client. It works fine on computers, but on tablets or mobile devices it just doesn't scroll.

There are menu items which trigger some jquery and scroll down to to the appropriate content when clicked - something I use often with no problems. These work on devices, but you can't use your finger to scroll.

The site is here: http://marcdeguerre.com/

I do have my html, body and other tags set to a height of 100%, thought that might be it. So I set them all to a height of auto when the viewport is below 767px wide. To no avail.

I changed all my background-attachments from fixed to scroll at that break point too. Didn't help either.

Has anyone come across this before?

Thanks a lot for any insight you may have!

Comment: Which devices are you having problems with? I've just tested it on an iPhone 6+, iPhone 6, iPad Mini and a Nokia Lumia 1020 with no issues.

Comment: I'm having trouble with my iphone4, and ipad. It works fine in a testing environment on my computer, but not the actual devices.

Comment: It turns out it was the wp super cache plugin. Changes weren't being recognized. It's working now, but I'm not sure which of the several changes I made to the css were the fix. I assume it was changing the html, body and other tags to a height of auto under 767px viewports.

Comment: ha! happens to me all the time, bloody caching! Best bet is to revert to a previous version and keep doing the changes again one by one till it works (assuming you can remember all the steps you took of course!)

Comment: Since you've solved your problem with no idea what it was, and the question contains no useful info anyway, I suggest you go ahead and close this, Eric. (See http://tinyurl.com/so-debug.)